# Can bookdown output in PDF/X-3 format?

Tags: r, pandoc, bookdown, xelatex

I have a book authored in R/Bookdown and would like to offer a print-on-demand option. Many book publishers require pdf/x-3 for printing.

How do I generate a pdf in this format?

Comment: Have a look at the `pdfx` package

Comment: Is this an rstudio package or are you referring to the CTAN package of the same name?

Comment: latex package. Sorry I was not aware that rstudio also uses this terminology